# Ruby on Rails: how do you add a class in a link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do you get a link_to to generate something like

```
<a class="myclass".....
```

this is my code

```
<%= link_to "link", :controller => :my_controller, :action => :index, :class=>("on" if request.path =~ /\/my_controller/ ) %>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you read the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you'll see the following example:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

This means the syntax for link_to is "link to something, then something else in braces, then another thing in braces." Another way of interpreting it is that the chunks have to be hashes.

```
link_to "link",
        { :controller => :my_controller, :action => :index }, 
        { :class=>("on" if request.path =~ /\/my_controller/ ) }
```

Which can all be placed on one line if you like.

Answer (score 7):

In your code, `:class` is being included in the `url_options` hash rather than `html_options`. Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to "link", {:controller => :my_controller, :action => :index}, {:class => ...} %>
```